What RPC to use
currently working on a project where I am trying to get minutely updates on around 1000 crypto wallets of al their holdings and the value of each token. From my knowledge, each wallet will take one request.. is this correct? If so, what RPC would you guys recommend?

There is a good list of RPC providers here
https://solana.com/rpc
Some providers have extended RPC methods that may be more useful then others
